# Type error in C

Tags: c, types

I'm just learning C typing and am wondering what's wrong with the following example. When I try to compile it I get the error: "format '%i' expects type int, but argument 2 has type 'int(*)(int, int)'.

```
   #include <stdio.h>

int difference (int x, int y);
int sum(int x, int y);

main(){
    int differ = difference(10, 5);
    int thesum = sum(3, 4);
    printf("differnece: %i, sum: %i \n", differ, sum);
}

int sum(int x, int y){
    return x + y;
}

int difference (int x, int y){
    return x - y;
}
```

Comment: Dude, if you change your original question to correct the initial mistake, people will have a hard time figuring out what your issue was anyway.

Comment: I reverted back to original form so everyone can see the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You used `sum` (a function) where you presumably intended `thesum` (an `(int)` variable).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
printf("difference: %i, sum: %i \n", differ, thesum);
```

You were passing to `printf` the function prototype, not the result of the invocation.